# Select File in Package and Project Explorer in Eclipse via code

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a file path of a file from an Eclipse project and I want to select the file in the package and/or the project explorer.

This is my solution for now, but it doesn't work:

```
public void showVersionInPackageExplorer() {
    [...]
    Object[] filesToSelect = files.toArray();
    IViewPart view;
    view = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()
            .findView("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.ProjectExplorer");
    StructuredSelection structuredSelection = new StructuredSelection(filesToSelect);
    view.getSite().getSelectionProvider().setSelection(structuredSelection);
}
```

Comment: How do you create `files`? What type of object are in the list?